# How I can fix "Dummy Output" on audio

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, alsa

Yesterday my audio was working properly, but today I just have a "Dummy Audio" entry. When I run `AlsaInfo` I get:

```
!!################################
!!ALSA Information Script v 0.4.64
!!################################

!!Script ran on: Fri Oct  6 12:19:21 UTC 2017


!!Linux Distribution
!!------------------

Fedora release 26 (Twenty Six) NAME=Fedora ID=fedora PRETTY_NAME="Fedora 26 (Workstation Edition)" CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:fedoraproject:fedora:26" HOME_URL="https://fedoraproject.org/" BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/" REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Fedora" REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=26 REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Fedora" REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION=26 PRIVACY_POLICY_URL=https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Legal:PrivacyPolicy Fedora release 26 (Twenty Six) Fedora release 26 (Twenty Six)


!!DMI Information
!!---------------

Manufacturer:      Acer
Product Name:      Aspire 4750
Product Version:   V2.01
Firmware Version:  V2.01
Board Vendor:      Acer
Board Name:        Aspire 4750


!!ACPI Device Status Information
!!---------------

/sys/bus/acpi/devices/ACPI0003:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT340E:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT3F0D:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0103:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C09:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0A:00/status      31
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:00/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:01/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:02/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:03/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:04/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:05/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:06/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:07/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:27/status   15


!!Kernel Information
!!------------------

Kernel release:    4.13.4-200.fc26.x86_64
Operating System:  GNU/Linux
Architecture:      x86_64
Processor:         x86_64
SMP Enabled:       Yes


!!ALSA Version
!!------------

Driver version:     k4.13.4-200.fc26.x86_64
Library version:    
Utilities version:  1.1.4


!!Loaded ALSA modules
!!-------------------

snd_hda_intel


!!Sound Servers on this system
!!----------------------------

Pulseaudio:
      Installed - Yes (/usr/bin/pulseaudio)
      Running - Yes


!!Soundcards recognised by ALSA
!!-----------------------------

 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xf0600000 irq 27


!!PCI Soundcards installed in the system
!!--------------------------------------

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)


!!Advanced information - PCI Vendor/Device/Subsystem ID's
!!-------------------------------------------------------

00:1b.0 0403: 8086:1c20 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: 1025:0506


!!Loaded sound module options
!!---------------------------

!!Module: snd_hda_intel
    align_buffer_size : -1
    bdl_pos_adj : -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
    beep_mode : N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N
    enable : Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y
    enable_msi : -1
    id : (null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null)
    index : -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
    jackpoll_ms : 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    model : (null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null)
    patch : (null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null)
    position_fix : -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
    power_save : 0
    power_save_controller : Y
    probe_mask : -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
    probe_only : 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    single_cmd : -1
    snoop : -1


!!HDA-Intel Codec information
!!---------------------------
--startcollapse--

Codec: Intel CougarPoint HDMI
Address: 3
AFG Function Id: 0x1 (unsol 0)
Vendor Id: 0x80862805
Subsystem Id: 0x80860101
Revision Id: 0x100000
No Modem Function Group found
Default PCM:
    rates [0x0]:
    bits [0x0]:
    formats [0x0]:
Default Amp-In caps: N/A
Default Amp-Out caps: N/A
State of AFG node 0x01:
  Power states:  D0 D3 CLKSTOP EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0, Clock-stop-OK
GPIO: io=0, o=0, i=0, unsolicited=0, wake=0
Node 0x02 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x6611: 8-Channels Digital
  Converter: stream=5, channel=0
  Digital: Enabled
  Digital category: 0x0
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
  PCM:
    rates [0x7f0]: 32000 44100 48000 88200 96000 176400 192000
    bits [0x1e]: 16 20 24 32
    formats [0x5]: PCM AC3
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x03 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x6611: 8-Channels Digital
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  Digital: Enabled
  Digital category: 0x0
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
  PCM:
    rates [0x7f0]: 32000 44100 48000 88200 96000 176400 192000
    bits [0x1e]: 16 20 24 32
    formats [0x5]: PCM AC3
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x04 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x6611: 8-Channels Digital
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  Digital: Enabled
  Digital category: 0x0
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
  PCM:
    rates [0x7f0]: 32000 44100 48000 88200 96000 176400 192000
    bits [0x1e]: 16 20 24 32
    formats [0x5]: PCM AC3
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x05 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40778d: 8-Channels Digital Amp-Out CP
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Con Mask", index=0, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Pro Mask", index=0, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Default", index=0, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Pincap 0x09000094: OUT Detect HBR HDMI DP
  Pin Default 0x18560010: [Jack] Digital Out at Int HDMI
    Conn = Digital, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x1, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x40: OUT
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x02
Node 0x06 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40778d: 8-Channels Digital Amp-Out CP
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x00 0x80]
  Pincap 0x09000094: OUT Detect HBR HDMI DP
  Pin Default 0x58560020: [N/A] Digital Out at Int HDMI
    Conn = Digital, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x2, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x40: OUT
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x03
Node 0x07 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40778d: 8-Channels Digital Amp-Out CP
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x00 0x80]
  Pincap 0x09000094: OUT Detect HBR HDMI DP
  Pin Default 0x58560030: [N/A] Digital Out at Int HDMI
    Conn = Digital, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x3, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x40: OUT
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x04
Node 0x08 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
--endcollapse--


!!ALSA Device nodes
!!-----------------

crw-rw----  1 root audio 116,  2 Oct  6 20:17 /dev/snd/controlC0
crw-rw----  1 root audio 116,  4 Oct  6 20:17 /dev/snd/hwC0D3
crw-rw----  1 root audio 116,  3 Oct  6 20:17 /dev/snd/pcmC0D3p
crw-rw----  1 root audio 116,  1 Oct  6 20:17 /dev/snd/seq
crw-rw----  1 root audio 116, 33 Oct  6 20:17 /dev/snd/timer

/dev/snd/by-path:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root  60 Oct  6 20:17 .
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root 160 Oct  6 20:17 ..
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  12 Oct  6 20:17 pci-0000:00:1b.0 -> ../controlC0


!!ALSA configuration files
!!------------------------

!!System wide config file (/etc/asound.conf)

#
# Place your global alsa-lib configuration here...
#


!!Aplay/Arecord output
!!--------------------

APLAY

**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

ARECORD

**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****

!!Amixer output
!!-------------

!!-------Mixer controls for card 0 [PCH]

Card hw:0 'PCH'/'HDA Intel PCH at 0xf0600000 irq 27'
  Mixer name    : 'Intel CougarPoint HDMI'
  Components    : 'HDA:80862805,80860101,00100000'
  Controls      : 8
  Simple ctrls  : 2
Simple mixer control 'PCM',0
  Capabilities: pvolume
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 255
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 0 [0%] [-51.00dB]
  Front Right: Playback 0 [0%] [-51.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]


!!Alsactl output
!!--------------

--startcollapse--
state.PCH {
    control.1 {
        iface CARD
        name 'HDMI/DP,pcm=3 Jack'
        value false
        comment {
            access read
            type BOOLEAN
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.2 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'IEC958 Playback Con Mask'
        value '0fff000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
        comment {
            access read
            type IEC958
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.3 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'IEC958 Playback Pro Mask'
        value '0f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
        comment {
            access read
            type IEC958
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.4 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'IEC958 Playback Default'
        value '0400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type IEC958
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.5 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'IEC958 Playback Switch'
        value true
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type BOOLEAN
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.6 {
        iface PCM
        device 3
        name ELD
        value ''
        comment {
            access 'read volatile'
            type BYTES
            count 0
        }
    }
    control.7 {
        iface PCM
        device 3
        name 'Playback Channel Map'
        value.0 0
        value.1 0
        value.2 0
        value.3 0
        value.4 0
        value.5 0
        value.6 0
        value.7 0
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type INTEGER
            count 8
            range '0 - 36'
        }
    }
    control.8 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'PCM Playback Volume'
        value.0 0
        value.1 0
        comment {
            access 'read write user'
            type INTEGER
            count 2
            range '0 - 255'
            tlv '0000000100000008ffffec1400000014'
            dbmin -5100
            dbmax 0
            dbvalue.0 -5100
            dbvalue.1 -5100
        }
    }
}
--endcollapse--


!!All Loaded Modules
!!------------------

Module
rfcomm
ccm
xt_CHECKSUM
ipt_MASQUERADE
nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4
tun
nf_conntrack_netbios_ns
nf_conntrack_broadcast
xt_CT
ip6t_rpfilter
ip6t_REJECT
nf_reject_ipv6
xt_conntrack
ip_set
nfnetlink
ebtable_nat
ebtable_broute
bridge
stp
llc
ip6table_nat
nf_conntrack_ipv6
nf_defrag_ipv6
nf_nat_ipv6
ip6table_mangle
ip6table_raw
ip6table_security
iptable_nat
nf_conntrack_ipv4
nf_defrag_ipv4
nf_nat_ipv4
nf_nat
nf_conntrack
libcrc32c
iptable_mangle
iptable_raw
iptable_security
ebtable_filter
ebtables
ip6table_filter
ip6_tables
bnep
vmnet
ppdev
parport_pc
parport
fuse
vmw_vsock_vmci_transport
vsock
vmw_vmci
vmmon
sunrpc
ath3k
btusb
btrtl
btbcm
btintel
bluetooth
ecdh_generic
intel_rapl
x86_pkg_temp_thermal
intel_powerclamp
coretemp
kvm_intel
arc4
kvm
acer_wmi
iTCO_wdt
sparse_keymap
gpio_ich
wmi_bmof
iTCO_vendor_support
irqbypass
ath9k
crct10dif_pclmul
crc32_pclmul
ghash_clmulni_intel
intel_cstate
ath9k_common
ath9k_hw
intel_uncore
intel_rapl_perf
mac80211
snd_hda_codec_hdmi
uvcvideo
videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_memops
videobuf2_v4l2
snd_hda_intel
videobuf2_core
ath
joydev
snd_hda_codec
cfg80211
videodev
snd_hda_core
snd_hwdep
snd_seq
snd_seq_device
i2c_i801
snd_pcm
media
snd_timer
snd
rfkill
soundcore
mei_me
mei
shpchp
lpc_ich
wmi
i915
hid_logitech_hidpp
crc32c_intel
serio_raw
i2c_algo_bit
drm_kms_helper
sdhci_pci
sdhci
drm
mmc_core
tg3
ptp
pps_core
hid_logitech_dj
video


!!Sysfs Files
!!-----------

/sys/class/sound/hwC0D3/init_pin_configs:
0x05 0x18560010
0x06 0x58560020
0x07 0x58560030

/sys/class/sound/hwC0D3/driver_pin_configs:

/sys/class/sound/hwC0D3/user_pin_configs:

/sys/class/sound/hwC0D3/init_verbs:

/sys/class/sound/hwC0D3/hints:


!!ALSA/HDA dmesg
!!--------------

[    4.778776] Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[    4.787107] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[    4.804639] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device 1.3M HD WebCam (064e:d20c)
--
[    4.810183] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
[    4.816818] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input11
[    4.860725] RAPL PMU: API unit is 2^-32 Joules, 3 fixed counters, 163840 ms ovfl timer
```

Not sure how to fix this. I tried to reinstall the kernel, but it didn't help.

Comment: You have a single soundcard (Intel HDA), but it sees only the HDMI codec. If there is a motherboard codec (built-in speaker, headphones) than that is missing. Look at the BIOS if there are settings to enable/disable the codec and/or soundcard. If you can run Windows on it, see what hardware info about the sound it provides. If you have a second soundcard, look for it (`lspci -nn`).

Comment: If remember it correctly, when I am still using windows, the built audio is realtek, I dont have any other soundcard installed. The bios setting is very minimal there are just a few setting I can change, and the audio codec is not there. BTW it just occurred today, I just noticed it when I tried to watch a yt video.

Comment: If you didn't change anything between yesterday and today, the only idea I have is "hardware fault".

Comment: If audio on Windows is working, we can rule out hardware fault. Can you check if this is the case and add it to the question? Did the system update itself yesterday? I have similar issues after my Fedora upgraded to 27 and I my machine is Acer Aspire too.

Comment: I fixed this by doing `usermod --append --groups audio <user>` as the superuser.

Comment: It might be mine was a hardware failure, I tried your solution but still it doesn't work using the speaker or on the audio jack. But it works on Bluetooth.

Comment: The last diagnostic I would suggest is a Live USB with another distro, for example Debian stable. If it refuses to work, you rule out Fedora as the issue, remove this tag, and try to repair the sound card or audio jacks/connectors.

Answer (score 6):

I got this problem after upgrade Fedora 22 to 27. It was caused by a new group; you must be member of the `audio` group to get access to the snd devices;

```
~ > ll /dev/snd/controlC*
crw-rw----. 1 root audio 116, 2 Mar 31 08:27 /dev/snd/controlC0
crw-rw----. 1 root audio 116, 9 Mar 31 08:27 /dev/snd/controlC1
```

Check your groups with `id`. I added with `usermod -G audio,... <myuser>` but there may be other ways.

Comment: In my case I was using a docker container in which Debian ran. The only device was a "dummy output". But as soon as I added the `audio` group to my user, I could hear all sounds again when using Steam Remote Play. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

For me this sometimes happens after Suspending.
What helped and restarted pulseaudio:

```
pulseaudio --kill
```

This got my audio back without having to restart the desktop session.
(Ubuntu 20.04, all default)

Answer (score 3):

It's a misconfiguration. Rename `~/.config/pulse`, then restart your Desktop Session (log out, log in)

Answer (score 1):

You should check if your audio hardware is detected:

```
# aplay -lL
...
aplay: device_list:268: no soundcards found...
```

If it isn't, install the *alsa-firmware* package:

```
dnf install alsa-firmware
```

And reboot your machine.

This solution and also the one about adding my user to the audio group (as other answer here explains) solved it.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, after updating the system, a similar error occurred with the lack of drivers for the sound.

The solution was to install the package:

```
sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-55-generic
```

and reboot

Answer (score 0):

I had the needs to run pulseaudio as a system-wide service and I was having the dummy output issue you've described.

In my case I've solved following this article https://rudd-o.com/linux-and-free-software/how-to-make-pulseaudio-run-once-at-boot-for-all-your-users and adding the pulse user in the audio group.